# xcalib: how to increase brightness back gradually?

Tags: brightness, xcalib

IMO `xcalib` is weird. Maybe it is because I don't know how color profiles work. But same effect that I achieve by decreasing my backlight brightness I just found out I can achieve with `xcalib -alter -contrast 90`. Why `contrast`? Before today I've been trying `xcalib -brightness` and results were *unexpected* (whitish blurry image). But I digress from the main question.

Seems (on my hardware at least) `xcalib -alter -contrast 90` decreases brightness **by** ~10% (100-90) something, that is next run it decreases further. Any way to increase back gradually (not resetting with `-clear`)?

P.S. Ubuntu 22.04